# flutter "firebase_messaging" and "localstorage" version solving failed

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

i'm building my app using Flutter.
I got problem to 'pub get'.

Here is my "pubspec.yaml" file

```
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_ble_lib: ^2.2.3
  permission_handler: ^5.0.0+hotfix.3
  flutter_blue: ^0.8.0
  http: ^0.13.1
  localstorage: ^3.0.6
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.7
  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0
  intl: ^0.16.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.9.1"
  flutter_native_splash: ^1.2.0
  firebase_mess*aging: ^10.0.3
```

when pub get for these package, i got below error code .

```
Because no versions of localstorage match >=3.0.6 <3.0.6+9 or >3.0.6+9 <4.0.0 and localstorage 3.0.6+9 depends on path_provider ^1.6.14, localstorage ^3.0.6 requires path_provider ^1.6.14.
And because path_provider >=1.6.4 <2.0.0-nullsafety depends on path_provider_platform_interface ^1.0.1, localstorage ^3.0.6 requires path_provider_platform_interface ^1.0.1.
And because path_provider_platform_interface <2.0.0-nullsafety depends on plugin_platform_interface ^1.0.1 and firebase_messaging_platform_interface >=2.0.0 depends on plugin_platform_interface ^2.0.0, localstorage ^3.0.6 is incompatible with firebase_messaging_platform_interface >=2.0.0.
Because firebase_messaging >=10.0.2 <10.0.4 depends on firebase_messaging_platform_interface ^3.0.2 and firebase_messaging >=10.0.4 depends on firebase_messaging_platform_interface ^3.0.3, firebase_messaging >=10.0.2 requires firebase_messaging_platform_interface ^3.0.2.
Thus, localstorage ^3.0.6 is incompatible with firebase_messaging >=10.0.2.
So, because dmsystem depends on both localstorage ^3.0.6 and firebase_messaging ^10.0.3, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because dmsystem depends on both localstorage ^3.0.6 and firebase_messaging ^10.0.3, version solving failed.)
```

i think 'localstorage' and 'firebase_messaging' are not compatible.

how can i solve this version problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try the newer version of localstorage -> **localstorage: ^4.0.0+1**.

It is compatible with f**irebase_messaging: ^10.0.4**